# Pandas Plotting Date Frequency

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am new to Pandas and trying to plot some data from a DataFrame but would like all DateTime values visible on the x-axis.  However, when I plot the data I am only seeing 5 out of the 25 DateTimes plotted. How can I specify to display all datetimes on the x-axis?  Below is my code as well as the chart generated that shows only 5 of the 25 datetimes plotted.

My DataFrame

```
0                  Degrees
10/21 14:55        93.1
10/21 15:10        92.3
10/21 15:25        93.5
10/21 15:40        95.2
10/21 15:55        93.1
10/21 16:10        93.8
10/21 16:25        95.1
10/21 16:40        90.8
10/21 16:55        91.1
10/21 17:10        92.4
10/21 17:25        94.3
10/21 17:40        94.6
10/21 17:55        94.6
10/21 18:10        95.5
10/21 18:25        98.6
10/21 18:40        95.7
10/21 18:55        97.0
10/21 19:10        95.8
10/21 19:25        96.6
10/21 19:40        95.7
10/21 19:55        91.3
10/21 20:10        95.6
10/21 20:25        97.6
10/21 20:40        95.3
10/21 20:55        95.3
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
desired_width = 400
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rcParams
import re

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 6
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

df.Degrees.plot(kind='line', color='maroon', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, marker='o', label="Test Report")

ax.legend(loc='lower right')
ax.legend(loc="lower left", fontsize=9, bbox_to_anchor=(0.0, 0.060))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=7.5)
plt.tight_layout()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Chart Output:

[image]

Comment: The dupe target should help.

Comment: Hi, I've added the suggested line based on the similar post to specify the x-ticks `plt.xticks(df.index, df['Degrees'])`  but end up with error: `TypeError: unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() < str()`. Do I need to change the format of my datetime index?

Comment: What is `df.index`?

Comment: That is the datetime index of the dataframe `10/21 14:55  to 10/21 20:55`. The type is `dtype='object'` after converting the time format.

Comment: Ah, you instead need: `plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df)), df['Degrees'])`

Comment: That worked but instead of df['Degrees']) I used the index df.index, end result `plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df)), df.index)`.  Thanks for your help.